# Populate occurrence value of variable in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a dataset and need to create a new variable that will populate the row-wise occurrence of value per the variable in the sorted dataset as shown below.

```
VAR1    VAR2 (to be created)
C1      1
C1      2
C1      3
C2      1
C3      1
C3      2
C4      1
C5      1
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
unlist(sapply(rle(as.character(df$VAR1))$lengths,seq))
#[1] 1 2 3 1 1 2 1 1
```

Comment: I am getting the error "Error in rle(dumdt$Client_ID) : 'x' must be a vector of an atomic type". Can you point out to what I might be doing wrong ?

Comment: Apologies. Got it to work. Needed to convert to a character list. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option using `rle` and `sequence`

```
with(df1, sequence(rle(VAR1)$lengths))
#[1] 1 2 3 1 1 2 1 1
```

---

Or with `ave`

```
with(df1, ave(seq_along(VAR1), 
        cumsum(c(TRUE, VAR1[-1]!= VAR1[-length(VAR1)])), FUN = seq_along))
#[1] 1 2 3 1 1 2 1 1
```

---

Or using `rleid` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, VAR2 := seq_len(.N) , by = rleid(VAR1)]
```